# UniswapV3 PoolDepolyer (variables overriding throught slots)

Tags: uniswap, storage, factory, slots

I cant understand Pool deployment using variables transfering throught slots.
How it works and why developers choosed that way of initialization(guess it's cheaper)?

Pool contract snippet(simplified):

```
contract UniswapV3Pool {

    address public immutable override factory;

    address public immutable override token0;

    address public immutable override token1;

    uint24 public immutable override fee;

    int24 public immutable override tickSpacing;

    uint128 public immutable override maxLiquidityPerTick;
    
    constructor() {
        int24 _tickSpacing;
        (factory, token0, token1, fee, _tickSpacing) = IUniswapV3PoolDeployer(msg.sender).parameters();
    }

}
```

And Deployer contract:

```
contract UniswapV3PoolDeployer is IUniswapV3PoolDeployer {
    
    struct Parameters {
        address factory;
        address token0;
        address token1;
        uint24 fee;
        int24 tickSpacing;
    }

    Parameters public override parameters;

    /// @dev Deploys a pool with the given parameters by transiently setting the parameters storage slot and then
    /// clearing it after deploying the pool.

    function deploy(
        address factory,
        address token0,
        address token1,
        uint24 fee,
        int24 tickSpacing
    ) internal returns (address pool) {
        parameters = Parameters({factory: factory, token0: token0, token1: token1, fee: fee, tickSpacing: tickSpacing});
        pool = address(new UniswapV3Pool{salt: keccak256(abi.encode(token0, token1, fee))}());
        delete parameters;
    }
}
```

Solidity version =0.7.6 (in snippets)
Contracts:
https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/tree/main/contracts

Answer (score 1):

Parameters in this case passed by `IUniswapV3PoolDeployer.parameters()` call
https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3PoolDeployer.sol

```
interface IUniswapV3PoolDeployer {

    function parameters()
        external
        view
        returns (
            address factory,
            address token0,
            address token1,
            uint24 fee,
            int24 tickSpacing
        );
}
```

Function call happens in `UniswapV3Pool` constructor

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol#L119

```
    constructor() {
        int24 _tickSpacing;
        (factory, token0, token1, fee, _tickSpacing) = IUniswapV3PoolDeployer(msg.sender).parameters();
        tickSpacing = _tickSpacing;

        maxLiquidityPerTick = Tick.tickSpacingToMaxLiquidityPerTick(_tickSpacing);
    }
```

And this call works without direct `.parameters()` implementation in `UniswapV3PoolDeployer` because:

```
The compiler automatically creates getter functions for all public state variables.
```

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#getter-functions

---

**Answering another part of my question**

Uniswap devs deploying new pools that way, because:

```
This is used to avoid having constructor arguments in the pool contract,
which results in the init code hash of the pool being constant
allowing the CREATE2 address of the pool to be cheaply computed on-chain.
```

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3PoolDeployer.sol#L6

And I think it saves some gas on Parameters deletion in `.deploy()` Pool Deployer function

---

More about `CREATE2` here:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/deploying-with-create2